# CSS for divs to stack without gaps

Tags: css, layout, html

On this example I have 3 divs, highlighted with a purple border:

[image]

They have a 450px width, and are floated left.  If they are all the same height, the third box at the bottom lines up fine, but they are variable height and I would like them to flow left to right, top to bottom without any gaps.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not without absolute positioning. Either make them all the same height or just position them with Javascript.

Comment: If you are using jQuery there's a plugin called Masonry that does exactly this. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: That's a pretty awesome plugin. +1.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a 2-column layout and everything will show up as you wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/zhvFK/

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be possible by using the CSS3 [column](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp) options, however these are not well supported and it probably wouldn't be a good idea anyway.

Either set a fixed height or split them into columns with floated divs.

Otherwise you will need a fairly complex js setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to put the divs on the left and the div(s) on the right in individual containers. All of the ones on the left will be inside of another div that is floated left, and all of the divs on the right will be in another div that is also floated left.

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3XVwB/

Answer (score 0):

Try making the top right element `float: right`, something like this:

```
<div style="width: 350px;">
    <div style="float:left;  width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color:Purple;"></div>
    <div style="float:right; width: 150px; height: 240px; background-color:Green;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;  width: 180px; height: 200px; background-color:Red;"></div>
</div>
```

([here's a jsfiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/hxhzG/))